# Компактная установка Visual Studio с минимальным набором компонентов

Tags: visual-studio

Добрый вечер. Мне нужно на планшет на 8.1 поставить VS. Потому, что носить весь день с собой ноут, что бы сдать 1 лабу не удобно, но проблема в том, что 2015 студия занимает больше 10 гиг, думал скачать express, но она отдельная для веба, отдельная для десктопа, Можно ли как-то установить студию с минимальным набором компонентов, что бы был asp.net и c# только, без бейсика, с++ и пр.? В старых версиях можно было выбрать, что устанавливать, а в новых такого нет. Буду благодарен за помощь с:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное, это оптимальный вариант. 2012 студия меньше 6гб хочет. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но есть ли возможность выбирать среди всех компонентов (как на 1 скрине), а не только дополнительных? Или эту возможность выпилили в новых версиях?

Comment: А использовать онлайн-компиляторы для сдачи лабы нельзя?

Comment: А существует VS онлайн? Даже не слышал о таком.
В том крыле, где я учусь, только 1 роутер в холле, и тот не добивает до кабинетов, да и не всегда вообще работает :/
Вроде 2012 версия занимает 6.5 гигов, но думал, может есть вариант покомпактнее. А то на 28гб ссд не разгонишься :(

Comment: А Вы сдаете лабу или VS? Я так понимаю, что сдается код, а не среда, в которой код набран. (Кстати онлайн компилятор для С++ от MS существует)

Comment: Я сдаю лабу, но запустить то мне ее нужно как-то. Может, быть подправить что-то.

Comment: Так и запустите и подправьте. Например, на том же [ideone.com] (http://ideone.com) можно сохраняться (там C# есть, кстати). И да... С# есть не только на вин, но и на лин. И код (если без ГУИ) замечательно кроссплатформенно переносится. А по этой [ссылке](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm) можно еще в разных терминалах и IDE поработать.